# Efficiency of adding bounds to haversine query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

First off, let me state that I am aware that MySQL is not ideal for GIS work, and that the latest versions have GIS extensions, but I do not have the ability to make use of either a new database or a new version of MySQL, so I am making do.

- I have a large MySQL database that includes two float columns, lat and lng.
- I need to retrieve rows that are within a certain distance from a point, defined by two floats: lat and lng.
- I need to get some idea of the relative (in)efficiency of the function, and the improvement possible by pre-calculating a bounding box in lat and lng points.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT *, 
( 3958.762079 * acos( cos( radians(42.2626) ) * cos( radians( `lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `lng` ) - radians(-71.8023) ) + sin( radians(42.2626) ) * sin( radians( `lat` ) ) ) )
AS distance
FROM `table` WHERE 1=1 AND 
(`lat` >= '40.815284441002' AND `lat` <= '43.709915558998') AND 
(`lng` >= '-73.758118021205' AND `lng` <= '-69.846481978795') 
HAVING distance <= 100
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 100
```

The first part of it is a definition of the Haversine Formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Then I have precalculated bounds. (using https://github.com/anthonymartin/GeoLocation.php)

The big question is, are these bounds being tested before I run the haversine function or after?  By extension, am I running this function on every row with every query, or just on those within the bounds?

Is this a serious enough calculation to be worth having the bounds at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my answer in the mySQL documentation...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

It looks like the "WHERE" clauses get evaluated first, then the column alias ("distance", in this case) is calculated for each result, as they are found, then the "GROUP BY() HAVING" (written here as the shorthand "HAVING") is run, then sorting and limits are applied.

So, with an index on 'lat' and 'lng', the initial WHERE should run very quickly.  Then, the Haversine calculation is only run on that much-smaller result set.  All in all, this should be a quite efficient solution.